# How do I use Tampermonkey to display a warning prompt in Gmail when sending an email outside my organization?

Tags: javascript, gmail, tampermonkey

I am trying to develop a script with Tampermonkey to warn users sending email outside organization with a warning box after they clicked the send button.

The user can close this warning box and cancel or send it.

I activated the script but nothing.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Gmail Warning Prompt
// @namespace    your-namespace
// @version      1.0
// @description  Display a warning prompt when sending emails to outside organizations in Gmail.
// @match        https://mail.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    function displayWarningPrompt(event) {
        const sendButton = document.querySelector('div[role="button"][data-tooltip*="Send"]');
        if (sendButton) {
            const recipients = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.vR[role="listitem"][email]'));
            const externalRecipientFound = recipients.some(function(recipient) {
                return !recipient.getAttribute('email').endsWith('@yourorganization.com');
            });

            if (externalRecipientFound) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const confirmation = confirm('Warning: You are sending an email to an external organization. Are you sure you want to proceed?');
                if (confirmation) {
                    // Allow sending the email
                    sendButton.click();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', displayWarningPrompt, true);
})();
```

I expect to see a prompt one time when the user clicks on the send button in Gmail when the recipient is outside the organization.

Comment: Debug it. Open devtools, find your script and set a breakpoint on `const sendButton` line, then click the button.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you have any debug tutorial, I don't see any error jumping inside the console...